# black screen in surfaceView after activity with dialog theme opened

Tags: android, surfaceview

My center activity has a surfaceView. When I open another activity and get back to this everything works fine. The problem appears when I open an activity which has a [dialog-theme](/questions/tagged/dialog-theme). When I return from this activity I see a black surfaceView. The strange thing is that in both cases I described before the same methods are being called. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I found that when I open the activity with the dialog theme the surfaceDestroyed of the surfaceview doen't been called. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with adding camPreview.setvisibility(vIEW.GONE) in onPause and camPreview.setvisibility(vIEW.Visible)in onResume().